# AWS bucket replication is running in private network when using s3 "sync" command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to synchronize two buckets that are located in different regions under different accounts using "sync" cli command in an EC2 instance. Because the data transit is totally handled by AWS after sending "sync" command, I don't what exactly happens inside AWS. I'm wondering if this bucket to bucket replication is running on private aws network? I know CLI use TLS to secure the communication between EC2 and AWS, but I also want to keep the data transit inside the private network.

If negative, is there any way to keep this replication remain in private network? VPC endpoint doesn't work in cross region case.
THX

Comment: I think S3 Cross-region replication works on the private aws backend. So this is usually used for replication of buckets across and withing regions.

Comment: What is `async`? It is not a standard AWS command. Can you point us to where you found it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sorry, writing miss. It should be "sync"

Comment: @Marcin I think so. Yet I haven't found any official documents to prove this conjecture

Comment: Same. Could not find any quote in aws docs confirming that aws private backbone is used for S3 CRR.  Thus it seems to be a speculation for now.

Comment: [New – Inter-Region VPC Peering | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-almost-inter-region-vpc-peering/) mentions "Data that passes between VPCs in distinct regions flows across the AWS global network in encrypted form. The data is encrypted in AEAD fashion using a modern algorithm and AWS-supplied keys that are managed and rotated automatically." While it is talking about VPC Peering, it might also apply to _all_ inter-region traffic.